# Retrieve database value from Shared layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I added a shared div in _layout that shows the current balance (since i want it to be shown in all pages of the website.)

[image]

Right now, The amount is Hard coded, I wrote 3000$ ,
How can i retrieve this value from the database?
There is no controller for the _layout page.
I seen in Google the option to use @Html.Action,
This is not working ( i only have Html.ActionLink)

Here is the part in _layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-6"></h1>
        <h1 class="col-4 text-center" style="font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;color:forestgreen;border-style:inset">
            <img src="~/Images/Coin.jpg" alt="Site Logo" style="height:30px; width: 30px" />
            Current Balance : 3000$
        </h1>
        </div>
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody();
        </main>
    </div>
```

Created HomeController :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.net Core, to execute the controller action and render the view, you could use the [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0). If you want to use the RenderAction method, you have to add the HtmlHelperViewExtensions, and add the @Html.RenderAction() method in the Html Helper, more detail information you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786859/html-partial-not-firing-controller-method-in-asp-net-core/64800959#64800959).

In your scenario, I suggest you could use JQuery Ajax to call the action method and get the data from the database, then in the Ajax success method update the page content. You could refer the following sample:

Code in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult GetMessage()
    {
        //query database, and get the data.
        return Content("10000$");
    }
```

Code in the Layout.cshtml:
Add a `<span>` to display the return data:

```
        <div id="txt_navbar_output">
            <h4 class="col-4 text-center" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:forestgreen;border-style:inset;">
                <img src="~/Images/Coin.jpg" alt="Site Logo" style="height:30px; width: 30px" />
                Current Balance : <span id="returndata">3000$</span>
            </h4>
        </div>
```

After page load, use JQuery Ajax call the action method and get the data, then update the content.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/Home/GetMessage",
            success: function (data) {
                //update the page content.
                $('#returndata').html(""); //clear the content
                $('#returndata').html(data); //add the latest data.
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The output like this: the value has been changed to "10000$".

[image]

**Edit**:

About the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index)" error, it seems that the JQuery reference not added success, try to add the JQuery reference before the JQuery script:

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>  
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Home/GetMessage",
                success: function (data) {
                    //update the page content.
                    $('#returndata').html(""); //clear the content
                    $('#returndata').html(data); //add the latest data.
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

You could also use the CDN reference:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The _layout.csthml resource as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Test</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="txt_navbar_output">
                    <h4 class="col-4 text-center" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:forestgreen;border-style:inset;">
                        <img src="~/Images/Coin.jpg" alt="Site Logo" style="height:30px; width: 30px" />
                        Current Balance : <span id="returndata">3000$</span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - Test - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer> 
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Home/GetMessage",
                success: function (data) {
                    //update the page content.
                    $('#returndata').html(""); //clear the content
                    $('#returndata').html(data); //add the latest data.
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Zhi,
Your url in Ajax is Home/GetMessage...
There is no Home folder in the shared folder,
Where can i add the GetMessage?  can i create contoller for the _layout.cshtml in the shared folder?

Comment: No, not create a controller in the shared folder. In your MVC application, add a `HomeController` in the Controllers folder,  then, in the `HomeController`, add a GetMessage action method, you could check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42b2J.png).

Comment: Can you send your entire _layout? 
I created the homeController (added screenshot in main thread) for some reason the ajax is not working....
getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):120

Comment: @Kobi About the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index)" error, it seems that the JQuery reference not added success, try to add the JQuery reference before the JQuery script.

Comment: Thanks, ok that is resolved, but i'm getting
https://localhost:44326/Home/GetBalance 404
I think it is because of how the endpoint pattern is defined?
Since the Home controller is not called from an Area

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

Comment: Yes, the 404 error is related to the endpoint pattern. Try to modify the code as below: `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>{ endpoints.MapControllerRoute( name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "area", pattern: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");  endpoints.MapRazorPages();});`

Comment: It is working now...
But endpoint pattern is not correct. i cant access all other pages

"No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44326/Category?area=Admin"

Comment: i can get the balance and i can access the home page of admin and user, but all other pages i get this error

Comment: I replaced The 2 endPoints order and now it works.
Thank you for all your help!